# How to assign a specific memory address to a pointer?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a memory address '0x8f820dae' on my computer
I want to store an integer value '2' in this specific memory location, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use this to communicate between processes? Or is this for some sort of embedded device?

Comment: title and body are different questions. Title would be `int * p = 0x8f820dae`. For the body there is an answer given already

Comment: How many bytes should be written under `0x8f820dae`? Just one (`0x02`), two (`0x0002`) or more?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Turbo C++ is not C++ btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this is a valid writable on your process memory address and by "an integer" you meant an `int`:

```
*reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x8f820dae) = 2;
```

Note that this will write the value `2` (0x00000002) to the address `0x8f820dae` (considering x86). Change the `<int>` type-parameter if you want to write a different numbers of bytes (i.e. `sizeof(int)` bytes will be written at the memory address).

Answer (score 1):

Typically like this:

```
*(int *)0x8f820dae = 2;
```

(Or use a C++-style cast if you prefer.)

Comment: C++ tag though.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using C-style casts in C++ when using POD types.

Comment: Same way as nothing wrong to allocate memory using C allocators, however not recommended.

Comment: @dedecos: there I would disagree - for POD casts we're just talking about syntax; for memory allocation you have two fundamentally different idioms.

Comment: It is showing this error: Cannot cast from 'unsigned long' to 'int *'

Comment: I disagree with this for another reason. there is no mention of the size that is to be written to and `int` has an ambiguous size in memory. I'd recommend `uint<8/16/32>` in this example

Comment: @TarickWellin: the OP specifically said "int" in the question - if he had specified a particular size of integer then I would have used the appropriate fixed size type.

Comment: @user11988476: what compiler are you using ? It [compiles for me without warnings or errors with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Z-_hre).

Comment: @paul , turbo c++

Comment: @user11988476 Time to upgrade then. There are several modern C++ compilers available at zero cost (to individuals). Turbo C++ dates from the last millennium.

Comment: @john True, but if OP is developing for DOS, he might be forced to use an old compiler. Hopefully OP is not using Turbo C++ because of other reasons.